# Update Active Directory (On-Prem) User Attribute via Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I tried to not bug you all, but I'm at a loss. I'll preface with, I'm still relatively new to PS, so my apologies for any ignorance.

Need: To update users' attribute (extensionAttribute1 to be precise) to "First.Last" (or rather, "givenName.Surname") for all users in AD.

Problem: When I try to run the Powershell below (I was trying 2 different methods for update, hence the commented out portion), I get the outputs below.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'ou=Users,ou=Test,dc=Sample,dc=Com' | 
    Select SamAccountName | 
    Export-Csv -Path 'c:\Scripts\AllUsersSamaccountname.CSV' -NoTypeInformation

$file="c:\Scripts\AllUsersSamaccountname.CSV"
(gc $file | select -Skip 1) | sc $file


$Users = Import-Csv -Path "c:\Scripts\AllUsersSamaccountname.CSV" -Header "AccountName"
     foreach($User in $Users){ 
     $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.AccountName -Properties extensionAttribute1 
     $ADUserG = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.AccountName -Properties givenName 
     $ADUserS = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.AccountName -Properties Surname
     #$ADUser.extensionAttribute1 = [Array]$ADUserG + '.' + $ADUserS
     Set-ADUser -Instance $ADUser -replace @{extensionAttribute1=([Array]$ADUserG + '.' + $ADUserS)}
     
}

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'ou=Users,ou=Test,dc=George,dc=Com' | 
    Select extensionAttribute1 | 
    Export-Csv -Path 'c:\Scripts\new-AllUserinfo6.CSV' -NoTypeInformation
```

**Output** for *Set-ADUser -Instance $ADUser -replace @{extensionAttribute1=([Array]$ADUserG + '.' + $ADUserS)*

```
Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Replace'. All values in the argument collection should be of 
the same type.
At line:17 char:44
+ ... er -replace @{extensionAttribute1=([Array]$ADUserG + '.' + $ADUserS)} ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.Set 
   ADUser
```

**Output** for *#$ADUser.extensionAttribute1 = [Array]$ADUserG + '.' + $ADUserS*

```
Exception setting "extensionAttribute1": "The adapter cannot set the value of property "extensionAttribute1"."
At line:16 char:6
+      $ADUser.extensionAttribute1 = [Array]$ADUserG + '.' + $ADUserS
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterSetValue
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are casting the givenName to an array.  More than likely that's causing the whole expression to return an array, which isn't acceptable for extensionAttribute1.

I didn't test this but rewriting the loop to something like below should work:

```
foreach($User in $Users)
{
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.AccountName -Properties extensionAttribute1 
    $ADUserG = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.AccountName -Properties givenName 
    $ADUserS = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.AccountName -Properties Surname

    $extensionAttribute1 = ($ADUserG.givenName + '.' + $ADUserS.Surname)
    $ADUser.extensionAttribute1 = $extensionAttribute1
    Set-ADUser -Instance $ADUser
}
```

Note: that you must reference the properties for givenName & Surname in order to concatenate them as strings.  Otherwise you are trying to add 2 user objects together and will get an error.

**Additional Info:**

If this were me I would write this to be more concise.  However, considering you are relatively new to PowerShell, I'd just make one recommendation.  In the loop you don't need to get the user account multiple times, something like the below should work and be a little faster.

```
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'ou=Users,ou=Test,dc=Sample,dc=Com' | 
Select-Object SamAccountName | 
Export-Csv -Path 'c:\Scripts\AllUsersSamaccountname.CSV' -NoTypeInformation

$file="c:\Scripts\AllUsersSamaccountname.CSV"
(Get-Content $file | Select-Object -Skip 1) | Set-Content $file

$Users = (Import-Csv -Path "c:\Scripts\AllUsersSamaccountname.CSV" -Header "AccountName")

foreach($User in $Users)
{
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.AccountName -Properties 'extensionAttribute1','givenName','Surname'

    $extensionAttribute1 = ($ADUser.givenName + '.' + $ADUser.Surname)
    $ADUser.extensionAttribute1 = $extensionAttribute1 
    Set-ADUser -Instance $ADUser 
}

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'ou=Users,ou=Test,dc=George,dc=Com' | 
Select-Object extensionAttribute1 | 
Export-Csv -Path 'c:\Scripts\new-AllUserinfo6.CSV' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi Steven, first thank you for the information. I attempted the second block you sent and receive this error message now.

Set-ADUser : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:18 char:5
+     Set-ADUser -Instance $ADUser -Replace @{extensionAttribute1 =  $e ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Comment: Worth noting that the first section in your comment returns this error message. 

Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser] does not contain a method named 
'op_Addition'.
At line:19 char:5
+     $extensionAttribute1 = ($ADUserG + '.' + $ADUserS)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: Which, is why I thought I had to use [Array]..?

Comment: The first error is because we weren't  referencing the sub-properties, so it was trying to add the 20 user objects together. What we really wanted was to add the given & surName properties which are simple strings. That's been corrected in both examples.

Comment: The second error means the parameters aren't compatible. `-Instance` can't be used with `-Replace`.  They are in different parameter sets... I updated the examples with the proper usage.

Comment: You beautiful son of a gun, bottom block worked like a charm this time. Thank you for taking the time to throw an assist my way. I'm so thankful for stack overflow and websites like it. Been a LOOONG time lurker and people like yourself help us newbs keep something resembling sanity... Thank you again!